# WordPress Blink Codes Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, blink

I use codes with blink;

**Jquery;**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var blink = function(){
        $('#blinker').toggle();
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(blink, 100);
    });
</script>
```

**Page;**

```
[full_column align="center"][su_button url="#basvuru" class="fancybox" background="#b21f30" size="6"] <div id="blinker">ÜCRETSİZ PROGRAMA BAŞVUR</div>[/su_button][/full_column]
```

Website: [www.varsiteam.com](http://www.varsiteam.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
       var blink = function(){
       $('#blinker').toggle();
    };

    setInterval(blink, 100);
});
</script>
```

If you look at console you will see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

To fix that you have to put your function inside of `$(document).ready` event. When you call `$('#blinker').toggle();` it tries to use jQuery object which is undefined if you not put it in `$(document).ready` event. That is how jQuery works.

Answer (score 0):

When you're working in WordPress, jQuery is loaded in a no-conflict mode.

So, you'll need to use `jQuery` and not `$`.

Your code should be:

```
var blink = function(){
  jQuery('#blinker').toggle();
};
```

Or if you want to wrap everything in your document ready event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var blink = function(){
    $('#blinker').toggle();
  };
    setInterval(blink, 100);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this ways does not work; www.varsiteam.com

Comment: You haven't used the snippet above in your code (line 134 in your source code)